# Adição de Array em um Hash durante um loop não persiste os dados até o final

Tags: ruby

tive que vim pedir ajuda aos senhores pois não consigo enxergar onde estou errado, certamente uma besteira. Estou lendo um *csv* e estruturando esses dados em um `Hash`, onde tenho um `header` como `key` e um `array` de `hashes` como valor.

```
 def programacao
    result = Hash.new([])
    header = nil
    csv_each_for(file_to('programacao/9')).each do |row|
      next if row[0].nil?

      if row[0].start_with?('#')
        header = row[0]
        next
      end
      # puts "HEADER #{header} / ROW: #{row[0]}"
      result[header] << ({
                            horario: row[0],
                            evento: row[1],
                            tema: row[2],
                            palestante: row[3],
                            instituicao: row[4],
                            local: row[5]
      })
    end
    result
  end
```

Lá vai o ponto estranho, se eu parar a execução durante o `loop` e verificar o valor de `result`, ele estará vazio, mas caso eu acesse uma chave específica ela está sendo persistida.

**Primeira iteração:**

```
[1] pry(#<Programacao>)> result
=> {}
```

mas result[reader]

```
[3] pry(#<Programacao>)> result[header]
=> [{:horario=>"09:00 - 9:50",
  :evento=>"Palestra",
  :tema=>"Reforma da Previdência",
  :palestante=>"Dr. Álvaro Mattos Cunha Neto",
  :instituicao=>"Advogado - Presidente da Comissão de Direito Previdenciário",
  :local=>"OAB"}]
```

**Segunda interação:**

```
[1] pry(#<Programacao>)> result
=> {}
```

enquanto com header

```
[2] pry(#<Programacao>)> result[header]
=> [{:horario=>"09:00 - 9:50",
  :evento=>"Palestra",
  :tema=>"Reforma da Previdência",
  :palestante=>"Dr. Álvaro Mattos Cunha Neto",
  :instituicao=>"Advogado - Presidente da Comissão de Direito Previdenciário",
  :local=>"OAB"},
 {:horario=>"9:00 -10:00", :evento=>"Solenidade de abertura do Estande", :tema=>nil, :palestante=>"Direção/Coordenações", :instituicao=>nil, :local=>"Faculdade Católica do Tocantins"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bastou substituir

```
result = Hash.new([])
```

por

```
result = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```